# Getting index of every optionmenu from multiple optionmenus

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Given multiple optionmenu with stringvar trace,how to get the index of every option menu's first option?

```
self.path_list=[]
def load(self,inputt):
    for i in range(0,self.x):
        self.variable = StringVar(root)
        self.variable.set("abc")
        self.variable.trace('w',partial(self.rb_mode,i=i))
        w=OptionMenu(root,self.variable,"Hello","World")
        w.grid(row=i+100,column=1)
        self.opt_menu.append(self.variable.get())
def rb_mode(self,*args,inx):
    self.variable.get.__setitem__(i)
    if(self.variable.get()=="Hello"):
        do something
```

[Here as shown,the drop down box index should be mapped with the corresponding file path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxTUe.png)

There are multiple dynamic drop down lists. Each drop down box index should be mapped with the corresponding path.

Am getting the output like:

World(printing 2 times which is the 2nd option,on clicking the 1st option)

Comment: Please provide some error or what exactly you have tried and where are you stuck right now?

Comment: This is the one which am in need of.